# Programmatically click on button camera Android

Tags: android, android-camera

I need the program to click on the Android camera button on a tablet, this is my code, and it works fine, but I need it to be done by program;
thank you so much.

```
private void sacoFotoIngresoLocal() {

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.example.android.fileprovider",  photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUERIMEINTO_TOMAR_FOTO);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "camera button" on most devices, including most tablets. Moreover, you cannot fake user input (hardware or software), for obvious security reasons.

If you want to take a photo without user involvement, use the camera APIs directly, or use a third-party library that wrap them (e.g., CameraKit-Android, Fotoapparat).